# Add a help-center link to "In need of moderator intervention" in the question flagging menu

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderation, help-center, help-center-proposed

In the flagging menu (see bottom for reference), almost every single category has a link to a clarifying help center entry. The only exceptions are:

1. Duplicates (which has a comprehensive submenu making complete misuse unlikely)
2. "In need of moderator intervention".

As it is, there seems to be significant confusion about number 2:

- [What are acceptable reasons for flagging as "Requires Moderator attention"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/what-are-acceptable-reasons-for-flagging-as-requires-moderator-attention)
- [Removing wrong duplicate flag when there is a correct duplicate flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300952/removing-wrong-duplicate-flag-when-there-is-a-correct-duplicate-flag)
- [Should we flag for moderator attention after close votes expire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260730/should-we-flag-for-moderator-attention-after-close-votes-expire)
- I recently unintentionally misused the feature myself for a duplicate case, but eventually got that resolved through chat instead.

-> I would like to see a help center entry containing examples for correct and incorrect usecases for this feature, and have it linked in the flagging menu.

- The current wording is quite broad, newer users do not have good intuition on what the responsibilities of a moderator are.
- This is the fallback option, increasing the likelihood of it being selected for situations where the user is unsure.
- I suspect that this change could save quite some moderator time, and in turn prevent users from feeling bad about wasting somebody's time.

Menu for reference:

[image: flagging menu]

Comment: There's a related discussion in the comments on this recent answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387406/334566